# how to draw/get this in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

[image]

I have to get this feature in my web page,i.e.on the left trapezoid a google map will be there  and on the right trapezoid another background will be there ,how to do that,
plz help

Comment: i have tried drawing a canvas and putting that thing of ,but it covers the whole page ,which i dont want!
what should i do next ?

Comment: @Sham - use javascript to convert a % into a number of pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an overlay with a linear-gradient as background : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmjvs/)**

---

Basic CSS:

```
#overlay {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(
    to bottom right,
    transparent 49.5%,
    rgba(255,0,0,0.5) 50%
    )
    ;
  pointer-events:none;/* avoid click being catched*/
}
```

Comment: can i change the background in any of the sides (left/right).I need two backgrounds

Comment: are those colors or image ?

Comment: @sham, with image as bg, you could do something like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nKjlA/

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hint for you, which should help you getting what you want. 
Try something like this:

```
#trapezoid {
border-top: 100px solid red;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 100px;
}
```

this is from the page 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: i have tried that but everytime i try to put some % value,it dissapers

Comment: thats true, because border-width does not support values in %.
but you could convert % in px with javascript on page-load.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/14881/site-background-pattern-07.jpg);
}

#triangle-topleft { 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid gray; 
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/mwUhZ/)

Comment: everytime i change the 100 px to % value ,why it dissapers

Comment: because its triangle made from css read here to get fair enough idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work